# why is my class undefined when exported like this?

Tags: typescript

#### folder structure

```
├── shared/
│   ├── index.ts
│   ├── formatters.ts
│   ├── validators.ts
|   ├── package.json
```

#### separate project

```
├── project/
│   ├── project.ts
│   ├── package.json
```

#### formatters

```js
export class A{
}
export class B{
}
```

#### validators

```js
export class C{
}
```

#### index.ts

```js
export * from './validators'
export * from './formatters'
```

#### project.ts (installed shared w/ npm)

```js
import {A} from 'shared'
console.log(A) //undefined
```

how ever if I were to have the index file look like this

```js
export { C } from './validators'
export { A, B } from './formatters'
```

then it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out the build wasn't working properly. I don't know why, but the import wasn't registered in the built index.js file